# Taking real and imaginary parts of indexed functions and speeding up ComplexExpand

Tags: list-manipulation, complex, performance-tuning

I am setting up a large system of ODEs and in order to use the IDA method (which is sig. faster for my system and thus attractive), I must split my equations into real and imaginary parts.

I am experiencing a severe bottleneck in taking real and imaginary parts of my functions, using `ComplexExpand`, and I suspect that this slowdown has to do with my inability to specify that the range of certain functions are real. A simple example is given below:

Consider two tables, whose elements I would like to decompose into real and imaginary parts:

```
A1 = Table[ar[n]+I*ai[n], {n, 1, 500}];
A2 = Table[(n+I*n),{n,1,500}];
```

Now, to find the real part of, e.g., `A1.A1`, I would take

```
Re[ComplexExpand[A1.A1]];
```

The timing for these computations, however, is radically different.

That is

```
Timing[Re[ComplexExpand[A1.A1]];]
```

> ```
> {0.203348, Null}
> ```

```
Timing[Re[ComplexExpand[A2.A2]];]
```

> ```
> {0.000585, Null}
> ```

So we see there is a difference of around `400`!

Intuitively, it would seem that if I can tell *Mathematica* to treat `{ar[n],ai[n]}` as being functions with ranges over the reals, I can significantly improve the timing. Right now the `{ar[n],ai[n]}` are effectively constants, but in the future they might be functions.

For the purpose of `ComplexExpand`, is it possible to have *Mathematica* treat these objects simply as real constants?

**Note:** For completeness, I add that the system of equations I am going to be decomposing, in terms of real and imaginary parts, will be a sum of maximum degree 4 polynomials in the variables `A[n][t]=Ar[n][t]+I*Ai[n][t]` where `n` is some index number on the dependent variables, which will take values between `1` and `N`(right now I have `N` at 40, but in the future it'll be something around `100` or `200`). For each equation, there are around `N+N^2` terms. For my governing equations, with `N=40`, this real/imaginary decomposition is taking around `3500` CPU seconds.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but try to reverse the order of `Re` and `ComplexExpand`, i.e., do `ComplexExpand[Re[something]]` to get rid of `Re` and `Im` in your expressions.

Comment: @LeoFang Thanks for the tip. I find that this commutation of the operations actually takes slightly more time than the original.

Comment: To Nick, as I said this isn't an answer to your question. Without knowing what your `ar[n]` and `ai[n]` exactly are, it's not easy to point you to the way out, so I just gave a general suggestion since there is a difference between, for example, `Re[ComplexExpand[x^2 - 2 x + 1]]` and `ComplexExpand[Re[x^2 - 2 x + 1]]` which might be crucial in your work.

Comment: @LeoFang Thanks again for the tip. I've edited my question a bit to add more of a description of my system.